# Improve efficiency of web building setup and processes - Wordpress on Mac

Tags: wordpress, ftp, mac

Can anyone see any ways in which I can improve my speed and efficiency with the following setup? Or if there are any obvious holes in my building process?

This is for building **Wordpress** websites on **Mac**:

1) I have a standard Wordpress setup that I work from which includes various plugins that I tend to use across all setups - thus cutting out the step of having to download them all the time!

2) My standard WP files are copied into a **Dropbox** folder - thus creating backups of the files.

3) I then open up **MAMP** and setup a local version.

4) I open up **Coda** and setup the FTP details so files can be uploaded to the live domain by using the publish button.

If anyone has any advice on how to improve this process then please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bad workflow.

Instead of using Coda's publish feature I would consider using Git instead.  There are many advantages to this.

1. Pushing changes to your server is just as easy.
2. It gives you source control and branching.
3. Coda's publish system could choke with local wordpress versus server updates resulting in overwritten files.  In Git you just setup an ignore file to exclude all files that you are not going to touch.
4. You can edit directly on the server and not worry about overwriting those.

Also, I'd consider using virtualhost X for domain names.  This way when you push any content in WP you don't have to do any DB changes to reflect different image paths.  There are a few easy mysql command to change these as well which I can dig up and post.